# Sharing code between Micro-services - is it justified in this situation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, microservices

There are so many answers and blog posts saying "never share code between microservices" and I wonder right now how I am supposed to follow that advice. I've got the following microservices and each of them is communicating via RabbitMQ:

[image]

The express server and the two different background services have completely different code, while the request workers are just multiple instances. Each request worker is supposed to process a request and return a direct reply to it once it is done with it (RPC).

**My question:**

I have written a class (`RequestScheduler`) which offers methods to schedule a request (e. g. `getProfile: Promise<IProfile>`). Since I am apparently not allowed to share code between microservices what about the code for the communication between the microservices?

I don't see a way how I could avoid sharing that code along with my microservices on the left side.

Comment: Could you please describe your question with more details, it's unclear which code you're avoiding to duplicate. If you your 2 background services share same code, maybe it's worth to extract it into separate microservice?

Comment: Well I am trying to avoid the code which helps me communicating between the microservices (e. g. scheduling requests as described), so no this can not be it's own microservice. One needs to have a bit background on RabbitMQ to see what is needed for RPC, but I am sure I would face the same issue if I would for example use REST for communicating.

Comment: package that code as a module

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides So you are also positive that shared code is okay in this case? I am confused because really everywhere I read "never share code" between these services.

Comment: never share business rules code perhaps? What if you have a logger? Do you also not `$ npm install` the hell out of it in every service? What makes this code different?

Comment: also I'll be rude here - it's downright stupid to vote to close this question as opinion based. +1 from me just for that

Comment: The only sane meaning of "do not share code" is "do not manage code that affects different microservices". If for example microservice A and B uses LibX in v1 then it is **completely** ok. Even necessary, how can you develop anything nowadays without libs? If microservice B upgrades LibX to v2 then it is ok, because microservice A does not have to do that. They are indeed independent. So pack common code into a lib and make sure that once "released" the code in the lib (in the version) doesn't change. If you want a change in the lib, create new version. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 8):

Cross-cutting concerns are often not as well documented in discussions I've seen about Microservices architecture - probably because on first blush they seem contrary to the concept (though they are not).  While developing our applications (first time using Microservices) we struggled with similar questions to what you are asking.  After speaking with some folks who have much more experience in it than we did at the time, we came to realize that the concept of Microservices is much more about **Domain** encapsulation so hard rules around size, library sharing, etc. are all secondary to the idea of a Microservice having a single responsibility (SRP) and owning a single, well-defined domain (DDD).

We have libraries (which we manage as NuGet packages) for wiring up new services to the event bus(es), managing Authorization, cross-service event logging, and even a standard Middleware for error handling - we share these across nearly all our services.

Though we haven't defined a hard rule on it, I would say we approach code reuse as "If all Microservices in our ecosystem require it, it *must* be available as a shared library.  If most of them could use it, it *should* be available as a shared library. 
 Each Microservice has the option as to whether or not it implements the shared libraries or rolls its own solutions."

So long as your shared code is distributed in such a way to allow each Microservice to independently manage its own upgrade and your shared code is free from any domain-specific language or concerns, by all means share away!

Comment: I agree with all the points in this answer. However, one thing I don't like about it is that if you fix a bug in one of those shared libraries for example, you need to re-deploy all of the microservices which kind of makes the system deployment-monolith. Another thing that I don't like is when a breaking change is made in one of the places in shared libraries which'll require updating all of the dependent microservices again. I don't see a way around these issues though so I still think this is the best approach..

Answer (score 1):

@kentor logging is a cross-cutting concern. If there is a company standard for logging and a module or library is made available for it, then you may use that library. It is shared but this is fine as logging is pretty isolated and should not interfere with your business domain logic or workflow. The general guideline in microservices is to not share code. Things that can be shared are libraries that don't changed very often like US States, color, etc. To answer your question `what about the code for the communication between the microservices`, I would say not to share this code. Sharing code this code/library to other applications can potentially introduce side-effect bugs.

Comment: Are you suggesting that writing communication lib from scratch each time is less error prone? Totally disagree. BTW every lib can potentially introduce side-effect bugs. That's the price you pay for not trying to solve the same problem over and over again, which generally seems to be totally more error prone and less effective. And IMO the "communication between microservices" is a great example of a custom lib that should be reused between microservices.

Comment: If you own the domain and the microservices, you can create a common lib that can be shared to other microservices in your domain. What I am trying to avoid is, if I have an API, I would not create a client library that I would distribute to my client consumers. AWS SDK, is different, although it is provided but it is maintained by a community and AWS people othern than those who work on the API itself.

Answer (score 0):

`code for the communication between the microservices` looks like kind of a library or a package for me, that would not be changed so often. Why not to use it as a package?

A good options is to make a package in private npm registry. Then you would be able to have different version of that package. So you will be on safe ground using semantic versioning.